# What does Imputer.fit with nan value do?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm learning machine learning using the scikit-learn library and I was puzzled when I see the code from [Scikit-learn tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/impute.html)

It has the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
imp.fit([[1, 2], [np.nan, 3], [7, 6]])       

X = [[np.nan, 2], [6, np.nan], [7, 6]]
print(imp.transform(X))
```

From what I understand, imputer is used to fill in the missing values, and that it uses some strategy like mean, median or mode. But I don't understand what these 3 lines of code are doing

```
imp.fit([[1, 2], [np.nan, 3], [7, 6]])       
X = [[np.nan, 2], [6, np.nan], [7, 6]]
print(imp.transform(X))
```

Why does it fit a matrix with `np.nan` ? And how these fitting affect the `imp.transform(X)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `imp.fit`, it calculates the value to replace in each column (in this case the `mean`).

You can access access what I keep in each column with: `imp.statistics_`

When you run `imp.transform`, it complete the `NaN` with the corresponding value (what is in `imp.statistics_`)

Comment: Thanks, it is clear to me now after looking what is inside `imp.statistics_`